# Cannot Load Image In IE5 And IE6 using Csssprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am using csssprites in my application. Css images is successfully loaded all browser except IE 6 and IE 7 . I dont know how fix this problem.

> For Your Reference My Html Pages
>   Blockquote

```
<body><div class="follow_us_blogger"></bogy>
```

> My stylesheet

```
.follow_us_blogger {background: no-repeat url('/design/csssprites/follow_us.png') 0 0px; width: 100px; height: 31px; float: right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your div and body tags properly.

```
<body>
<div class="follow_us_blogger"></div>
</body>
```